# What is the meaning of this property in my css file ?behavior: url(MyUrl)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

in a css file of a project I see this below code:

```
    {

    behavior: url(Mylink.htc)

    }
```

I dont Know what that means,it didnt work on Firefox,could you help me to know what is this,after that maybe i could find the replace statement in firefox?!

Comment: -1: Ever thought of using google? https://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=behavior+css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `behavior` property is for Internet Explorer version 5+. `behavior`lets you attach a script using CSS in order to implement DHTML (Dynamic HTML) components.
It's only supportet by IE (up to version 9) but no other browsers.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior

You can use it to fix things for IE that are not supportet by default, for example transparent PNG files in (very) old IE versions:
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

[MS official website:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "Support for element behaviors and HTML components (HTCs) has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5."

Answer (score 0):

A HTC file is usually used to patch support for specific `CSS` rules on older browsers. For example, CSS3 Pie (http://css3pie.com/about/) is used to add support to basic `CSS3` declarations such as `border-radius`, `gradients`, `rgba`, etc...

I believe `behavior` is supported by IE only.